# GLSL for depth only with GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT texture format

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, intel

my situation is when I deal with some depth data from a RGBD camera by GLSL. The information of the depth texture is below:

```
internal Format = GL_LUMINANCE16UI_EXT
Format = GL_LUMINANCE_INTEGER_EXT
DataType = GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT
```

My Vertex shader is empty:

```
#version 330
layout(location = 0) in vec4 in_position;
void main()
{ 
    gl_Position = in_position;
}
```

My Fragment shader is

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 texcoord;

out uint FragColor;

uniform usampler2D gSampler;

void main()
{
.
.
.
    FragColor = ...;
}
```

And my Geometry shader is:

```
#version 330 core

layout(points) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 4) out;

out vec2 texcoord;

void main() 
{
    gl_Position = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    texcoord = vec2(1.0, 1.0);
    EmitVertex();

    gl_Position = vec4(-1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    texcoord = vec2(0.0, 1.0); 
    EmitVertex();

    gl_Position = vec4(1.0,-1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    texcoord = vec2(1.0, 0.0); 
    EmitVertex();

    gl_Position = vec4(-1.0,-1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    texcoord = vec2(0.0, 0.0); 
    EmitVertex();

    EndPrimitive(); 
}
```

This code works well in my **NVIDIA**, but **Intel** driver (Intel 5th Gen). Therefore I change the depth texture into format as follows:

```
internal Format = GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16
Format = GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT
DataType = GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT
```

It can work without any error log when I check with glerror and glGetShaderInfoLog, but it **only return Zero** from the shaders. Do I have to change something within my shaders due to the new texture format?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to write to `gl_Position` in the vertex shader?

Comment: @BDL I have tried to add the gl_Position into the vertex shader as I edited, but it still nothing different with that.

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault. I oversaw the geometry shader. You are right: When using a geometry shader, there is no need to write to `gl_Position` in the vertex shader.

Comment: First of all, nothing in the above shaders is influenced by you choosing the texture format of what I suppose is the depth texture of the framebuffer object you render to. Not writing to `gl_Position`in a vertex shader results in the corresponding **input** in the geometry shader to be undefined - this however, is not an error, you just cannot rely, in general, on any inputs not written in the previous shader stage. I couldn't find anything in the specs that states that the geometry shader is not invoked or anything. This looks like an Intel bug - but I'd be very careful with that assumption.

Comment: Do you have the means to test this on an AMD implementation or a core GL 3.3 conforming software implementation like the Mesa LLVM softpipe? BTW, since you're trying to draw a full screen quad, why not define the quad with two triangles and simply passing the vertices trough the vertex shader? I'd assume this is the most common way (albeit yours should work too).

Comment: @thokra Thank you! I use 'glFramebufferTexture2DEXT' with GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT as attachment, and also attach 'glFramebufferRenderbufferEXT' with GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT when I check my FBO. Is that reasonable?

Comment: Fitst, since you're targeting core GL 3.3, I cannot Stress enough, that you're not supposed to use the EXT version of an extension or the ARB extension. Just use the what the core already offers. Extensions are supposed to augment core functionality - not replace it. Second, if you need a depth texture, just use a depth texture. You don't need and don't want a depth renderbuffer.

Comment: I find out that I have no color texture attached in FBO, because it is a depth data (I only have a texture in depth component...). It seem not right, but how can I do to fix that??

Comment: @thokra thank you! I try to use the depth texture as attachment only without render buffer, and I get 32768 in every pixel of the texture(at least not zero..) so weird..